# Visual Studio 2013 breakpoints aren't hit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I recently installed visual studio 2013. In VS2013 i've opened a VS2010 solution.
As i wished to debug the application, i've set some breakpoints on code that are **always** hit. secondly i've included the option to break on exception (so i know exactly where it went wrong).

```
yet when i run the application (in Debug)
```

- The exception isn't caught. The exception goes through the normal channels of handling without popping up to me.
- None of the breakpoints are hit.

The solution had `never such problems in VS2010`. Another `solution (built & created under VS 2013) doesn't give any problems during debugging`. With all the exceptions being thrown and all the breakpoints being hit.

What have i done wrong?

What i've tried sofar:

- reinstall VS2013
- Changed targeted framework
- Clean & rebuild
- Attached to process
- ....

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you attached the process, have you manually  detemine the type of code to debug ?
[image]

Comment: Everything is the same exception the `Common Language runtime exceptions `. There i've also checked `Thrown`

Comment: sorry, changed my answer, maybe you should check the what kind of code should be debugged... managed code or unmanaged code/native code, something like that....

Comment: What happens if you choose `Automatically`? I suppose it would choose the managed code? or am i wrong.